# Under which probabilistic assumptions is this estimation approach correct?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, conditional-probability, bayesian

trying to tackle a problem, I ended up having built a model $ p(\boldsymbol{x}_{i}|\boldsymbol{y}_{i,j}, \boldsymbol{x}_{j}) $ which gives me for different $ \boldsymbol{y}_{i,j} $ observations made by $ \boldsymbol{x}_{j} $, a new PDF of $ \boldsymbol{x}_{i} $. My ultimate goal is to obtain the best estimate for it, $ \hat{\boldsymbol{x}_{i}} $, given my $ \boldsymbol{y}_{i,j} $ observations. The most typical approach I have seen being used (from others who faced the same problem and made other models) is the:

\begin{equation}
\widehat{\boldsymbol{x}_{i}}=\arg \max_{\boldsymbol{x}_{i}} f(\boldsymbol{x}_{i}) \prod_{j \in \mathcal{O}} f(\boldsymbol{y}_{i,j} \mid \boldsymbol{x}_{i}, \boldsymbol{x}_{j})
\end{equation}

However, I tried using instead simply the following and it worked just fine:

\begin{equation}
\widehat{\boldsymbol{x}_{i}}=\arg \max_{\boldsymbol{x}_{i}} \prod_{j \in \mathcal{O}} p(\boldsymbol{x}_{i} \mid \boldsymbol{y}_{i,j}, \boldsymbol{x}_{j})
\end{equation}

I would like to ask why is that happening? What does the fact that both appear to work, suggest about their relationship? I did not mention the underlying assumptions (because I am not quite sure), therefore, I would like some help in identifying mathematically those.

Thank you for your time.

*Some further information regarding $ \boldsymbol{x}_{i} $, $ \boldsymbol{y}_{i,j} $, $ \boldsymbol{x}_j $ and their relation:

$ \boldsymbol{x}_{i} $ is the position of some node in 3D space. Assume that this node is emitting one single impulse signal. $ \boldsymbol{y}_{i,j} $ is the measurement of that signal from another node (namely node $ j $), whose position is "known" to us. A measurement depends only on the distance between the transmitting and the receiving node (the model of this dependency is the same for all receiving nodes). Therefore, given some measurement $ \boldsymbol{y}_{i,j} $ and the position of the receiver $ \boldsymbol{x}_j $, there is a distribution about where $ \boldsymbol{x}_{i} $ is.

The following graph depicts my system where my actual goal is to find the best position estimation for all nodes $ \boldsymbol{X} $ (their positions are independent to each other) because, in fact, I do not have any prior knowledge about them (the knowledge gets built iteratively via my optimization process).

[image: System]

So in fact, after optimizing $ \boldsymbol{x}_{i} $, I continue optimizing iteratively one by one all the rest of $ \boldsymbol{x}_{j} $'s (which become the new $ \boldsymbol{x}_{i} $ on each step) using the previous estimations of the $ \boldsymbol{x}_{j} $'s when available (else I am using a random position). I have practically seen that this method converges to a correct solution where nodes are in a relative reference system (since my initial positions are random) placed.

Comment: How are $x$ and $Y$ related? Are both random? What are the $f$s in your notation and how they relate with the $p$s? At any rate, $f(x) f(y_i \mid x)$ is _arguably_ the joint distribution $f(x, y_i)$ and so, the likelihood principles makes it preferable over $p(x \mid y_i)$ (which is the density of $x$ given $Y = y_i$?).

Comment: Note that $p(x \mid y_i) \propto  f(x, y_i)$ where the proportional constant is _positive and "universal" (relative to $x$)_. So, the two maximisations should result in the same $\hat x.$ Did you get the same $\hat x$?

Comment: what is the function f?

Comment: f(x) I think is the prior belief about x position

Comment: I made a change to also reflect the position of the observing node, because I think I had provided the formulations in a wrong way. Does this make some more sense?

Comment: Your notation suggests that  the signal $\ y_{i,j}\ $ arriving at node $\ j\ $ is unequivocally known to have been emitted by node $\ i\ $.  Is that the case?

Comment: yes, this is always the case